# What was the area of Nazi Germany at its height?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, germany, political-geography

The only number I’ve been able to find is the area of it in 1939, but it obviously got a lot bigger after that.

Comment: Do occupied/conquered countries, with their own governments (like Vichy France) count as Nazi Germany?

Comment: @DJohnM yes and no; usually when you answer these questions you also mention things like client states, allies, and sphere of influence, so for example Napoleonic France itself is not much larger than modern France but its sphere of influence covered almost all of continental Europe. See also [a similar question with excellent answer here](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/21273/2957).

Comment: @DJohnM Optimally, I'd like to know with and without.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the only area annexed to Germany proper after 1st September 1939 were Alsace-Moselle, as well as some parts of Poland (Dantzig, Łódź, Katowice area). Other areas were occupied, not annexed, which is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrmacht

At the height of the territorial expansion in 1942, Nazi Germany controlled more than 3,898,000 square kilometers of territory.

See the graphical illustration, "Nazi Germany and Europe, 1942," in Michael Freeman (1987). Atlas of Nazi Germany, p. 135.

Comment: Thanks, does that include all occupied territory? Like Vichy France and such?

Comment: Yes. ...........

Comment: In which case your answer is totally wrong.